# Flask-Security, dynamic url prefix for multilingual page (with Flask-Babelex)

Tags: python, flask, flask-security, flask-babel

I am adding Flask-Babelex to my website.
I register blueprints with url_prefix as such:

```
from app.main import bp as main_bp
    app.register_blueprint(main_bp, url_prefix="/<lang_code>")
```

I set up babel.localeselector as follows:

```
@babel.localeselector
    def get_locale():
        if not g.get('lang_code', None):
            g.lang_code = request.accept_languages.best_match(app.config['LANGUAGES'])
        return g.lang_code
```

Then in the routes.py file of the respective blueprint I add:

```
@bp.url_defaults
def add_language_code(endpoint, values):
    values.setdefault('lang_code', g.lang_code)


@bp.url_value_preprocessor
def pull_lang_code(endpoint, values):
    g.lang_code = values.pop('lang_code')
```

Basically, I am following what's been done [here](https://medium.com/@nicolas_84494/flask-create-a-multilingual-web-application-with-language-specific-urls-5d994344f5fd), and it's been working pretty well.
What I cannot seem to be able to achieve, is force Flask-Security-Too to work with this variable url_prefix.

If I do not change anything in flask-security configuration, and access localhost:5000/change_password it throws "UnknownLocaleError: unknown locale 'change_password'" at me, which is understandable.
If I access localhost:5000/pl/change_password, I get "AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'lang_code'".

Now I can set up the SECURITY_URL_PREFIX config parameter to "/<lang_code>", but then I get "AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'lang_code'" as well.

How can I pass the information what lang_code is to Flask-Security?

**Edit:** 
Config:

```
SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT = os.environ.get("SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT")
SECURITY_REGISTERABLE = True
SECURITY_CONFIRMABLE = True
SECURITY_CONFIRM_REGISTER_FORM = ExtendedRegisterForm
SECURITY_TRACKABLE = True
SECURITY_CHANGEABLE = True
SECURITY_RECOVERABLE = True
SECURITY_CHANGE_URL = "/change_password"
SECURITY_POST_LOGIN_VIEW = "/dashboard"
SECURITY_POST_CONFIRM_VIEW = "/welcome"
```

Versions:

- Flask-BabelEx==0.9.4
- Flask-Security-Too==3.4.5

Comment: Need some additional info - Flask-Security-Too doesn't support Flask-Babel until (unreleased) 4.0.0 - nor does (I believe) the original Flask-Security. Also - /change-password isn't the 'default' endpoint - so you have changed that as well .. Please provide more version and configuration info. Thx.

Comment: Thx for reaching out. Regarding Babel, I took a mental shortcut calling it Babel, while in fact it is Flask-BabelEx (I edited the post for clarification). I added version info and relevant config (nothing fancy has been changed, to be honest)  in the main post.

Comment: Another thought - flask-security creates its own blueprint (default name "security") It doesn't appear you have added "url_defaults" and "url_processor" to that blueprint. You could use the Flask .iter_blueprints to go through all of them.